# Saving to two different Firestore databases with dialogflow

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I'm making an actions on google project that will require adding data to two different **Cloud Firestore**. For some reason when I trigger the intent, it will only save to the original **Cloud Firestore**, but not the new one.

For simplicity, I'm going to refer to the original Cloud Firestore as "DB1" and the new one/ second one as "DB2"

Here's what I had tried:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const {WebhookClient} = require('dialogflow-fulfillment');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const {google} = require('googleapis');
const {
 <Basically All of the libraries / AOG functions>
 } = require('actions-on-google');


const defaultAppConfig = {"<FIREBASE CREDENTIALS FOR DB1 >"}     
const OtherAppConfig = {"<FIREBASE CREDENTIALS FOR DB2>"}

const defaultApp = admin.initializeApp(defaultAppConfig);   // DB1
const otherApp = admin.initializeApp(OtherappConfig, 'Other');   // DB2
const db = admin.firestore(functions.config(defaultApp).firebase); //DB1
const ab = admin.firestore(functions.config(otherApp).firebase); // DB2

const app = dialogflow({
debug: true,
clientId: '<DIALOGFLOW CREDENTIALS>'
});


app.intent('DB2 Write', (conv) =>{
   conv.ask('Okay I made the write to DB2');
   var data = {
   name: 'This is a Test write'
   };
   var setDoc = ab.collection('Test').doc('Write').set(data);
});

exports.dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

Sorry if some parts are unnecessary, I wanted to include as much information as I could (I might be missing something that someone else sees).

To sum up what I thought would happen, I thought when I triggered the intent 'DB2 Write' that it would write 'This is a Test Write' to DB2, however it just keeps writing the message/data to DB1.

How do I get this working so it will write to my second Cloud Firestore or "DB2" when this intent is triggered?

Thanks for the help!

**Note:** If it makes a difference, I'm using the dialogflow inline editor for this code.

**____________________________________________________________________________**

**Update:** Here is what I have tried/ updated and it still writes to DB1

```
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(); 
const db = admin.firestore();

const otherAdmin = require('firebase-admin'); 
otherAdmin.initializeApp({
   credential: otherAdmin.credential.cert(OtherAppConfig)
   },'Other');
const ab = otherAdmin.firestore();
```

and as well:

```
admin.initializeApp(defaultAppConfig);
var otherApp = admin.initializeApp(OtherAppConfig, 'other');
console.log(admin.app().name);  // '[DEFAULT]'
console.log(otherApp.name);     // 'other'
// Use the shorthand notation to retrieve the default app's services
var db = admin.firestore(functions.config().firebase);
// Use the otherApp variable to retrieve the other app's services
var ab = otherApp.firestore(functions.config().firebase);
```

**I'd like to note, the credentials I'm using for "OtherAppConfig" and "defaultAppConfig" were taken from the Firebase private key**.  ie: firebase console > project overview > service accounts > generate private key. Could this be the problem?

Comment: I see you are using `ab` to write a document.  You are not also using `db` to do the same.  Also it appears you are not handling the promise returned in `setDoc`.  You are almost certainly going to have to do something about that.

Comment: Sorry for clarification, I have other intents that use 'db' that works fine, but when I used 'ab' or DB2 it wrote to 'db' or DB1

Comment: There is 2 types of realtime database in firebase, cloud firestore and realtime database what is yours?

Comment: cloud firestore, I'll update

Comment: Are these two different projects?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is thus:

A Dialogflow project and a Firebase project are the same under the hood. This cool,  as your Firebase Functions will know intuitively connect with Dialogflow and your database without a lot of manual configuration.

However, if you have two databases from different Cloud Projects, you will need to do some additional configurations to connect securely. I'm not sure what your `AppConfig`s contain, but they may not be sufficiently setup. As such, the Firebase setup may be pulling the default (current project) app and database when you're grabbing the functions config.

You may want to, for your second project, download the service key. Then you can load it as a file or directly as JSON in your startup routine.

This snippet below should work the way you want.

```
// Setup 1st db, this project's db
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(); // Initialize with default params as we get it by default
const db = admin.firestore();
// Setup 2nd db
const otherAdmin = require('firebase-admin'); // We can import twice
const myOtherServiceKey = { ... }
otherAdmin.initializeApp({
  credential: otherAdmin.credential.cert(myOtherServiceKey)
});
const ab = otherAdmin.firestore(); // This should be the DB of our second project
```

Comment: **I get the following error when running this -**  Detailed stack trace: Error:               
                                                                                                                             The default Firebase app already exists. This means you called initializeApp() more than once without providing an app name as the second argument. In most cases you only need to call initializeApp() once. But if you do want to initialize multiple apps, pass a second argument to initializeApp() to give each app a unique name.

Comment: I had this exact same problem, but the code I provided above solved this error

Comment: Does the snippet above work if you provide a name in the second `initializeApp`?

Comment: No error, but it keeps writing to DB1.  I'll post a snippet of what I'm doing, I might be doing it wrong

Comment: Under the "update" section in my question is what I have been trying